# Pandas read_excel, 1 row header in first sheet but not other sheets

Tags: python, excel, pandas

There is a title in row 1 of the first sheet but not in other sheets.  Is there an easy way to account for this?

I'm pretty sure I can solve this in a roundabout way (uploading first sheet in one read_excel, then getting the rest of the sheets in a separate read_excel).

Assume 1 workbook and 2 sheets:

```
all_sheets = pd.read_excel('test.xls', sheetname=None, header=0 )

In [149]: sheet1 = all_sheets["Sheet1"]
Out[149]: sheet1
  This great excel workbook was created on :2016-04-01
0             Column_name1        Column_name2        Column_name3
1               Gary                   23                Paid
2               John                   26                Paid

In [149]: sheet2 = all_sheets["Sheet2"]
Out[149]: sheet2
             Column_name1        Column_name2        Column_name3
0               Patrick                35                Paid
1               Josh                   23                Paid
2               Justin                 26                Paid
```

Comment: do you want to merge data from all sheets into one using column names from the first sheet?

Answer (score 2):

You might have to load your sheets separately and use `skiprows` to skip the first row in the first sheet. Not sure you can treat sheets separately in one go.

`sheet1 = pd.read_excel('test.xls', sheetname="Sheet1", header=0, skiprows=[0] )`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want to use headers from the first sheet and merge data from all sheets into one data frame:

```
import collections
import pandas as pd

fn = r'test.xls'
first_sheet_name = 'Sheet1'

df_dict = pd.read_excel(fn, sheetname=None, header=None)
# sort 
df_dict = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(df_dict.items()))

df = pd.concat(df_dict.values())
df.columns = df.iloc[0]
df = df.ix[df.index > 0]
```